# Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

We are working on IE Automation using Selenium Web driver in C#.Net.

We are getting an exception in handling model popup window. We supposed to do below the action.

When we click on Link button it will open a popup window then we need switch to popup window selecting check box options and click on Submit button.

When clicking on Link button we are able to open the popup window. But here we are facing an issue like the child popup window is not loading with data and getting HTTP 500 Internal server Error.

I don't understand sometimes it was working properly with the same code but not all the times I am getting above issue when I am trying to perform above actions on child window.

is this any IE settings issue or my code issue even i ignored protected mode settings in IE settings.

I am trying with below code :

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ByNewNotes']")));
```

(or)

```
string jsWindowString = "NewWindow('pop_Type.jsp?Type=External&IuserId=NUVJK50'," + sessionId + ",'400','500');return false";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(jsWindowString);
```

Could you please help on this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried wait code

Comment: yes i tried 
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath("//*[@id='ByNewNotes']")))).Click();

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ExpectedConditions.ElementEx‌​ists` use `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` or `presenceOfElementLocated`

```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
     WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(""//*[‌​@id='ByNewNotes']")));
     element.click();
```

Either Try to use `FluentWait`. Create a by function of your element which you want to wait and pass it in below method

```
WebElement waitsss(WebDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
Wait<WebDriver> wait =
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
{
public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
}});
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

We had the same issues and solved it with this simple way.